# Where did Steinbeck write about the smoke stacks at Moss Landing?

Tags: identification-request, john-steinbeck

I was at Elkhorn Slough today, and the captain of the boat I was on said that the "smoke stacks" (or whatever they are now called) were built in the 1950s or 1960s. But I recall John Steinbeck mentioning them in a book of his, and I was pretty sure it was *Tortilla Flat* (1935). But now I'm wondering if it was perhaps in *Travels with Charley* (1962).

Does anybody know where this reference to the smoke stacks of Moss Landing in Steinbeck's writings appear?

BTW (fun fact): Moss Landing is the exact midpoint of California, from a vertical or North/South perspective, disregarding East/West considerations.